# (Aggregation) Can't find a codec for class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation

can you, please, help me with the following?

I have the error above in the repository given below

```
@Repository("polygonQueryRepository")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PolygonQueryRepositoryImpl extends PolygonRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations operations;

    public List<DBObject> findPolygonsMatchingGivenPointAndInputAggregate(Double lat, Double lng, String band) {
        GeoJsonPoint point = new GeoJsonPoint(lat, lng);
        MatchOperation operation = match(Criteria.where("location").intersects(point).and("attributes.band").regex(band));
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(Polygon.class,
                unwind("attributes.transponders"),
                operation);
        AggregationResults<DBObject> result = 
        operations.aggregate(aggregation,"Polygon",DBObject.class);
        return result.getMappedResults();
    }
}
```

I've previously read that I need to register codecs when defining MongoTemplate bean. So I did - and still no luck.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig {

    @Value("${mongo.db.name}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${mongo.db.host}")
    private String dbHost;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()).build();
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(dbHost,options), dbName);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty self explanatory. MongoDB does not use a `GeoJsonPoint` data structure. Since this is a custom function or at least implemented in an external library, you either need to extend with a serializer, or ( making some sense here ) simply supply the expected BSON structure you are supposed to do. So the latter would be advised, particularly since "said function" actually has the order incorrect where GeoJSON is actually ordered `longitude` then `latitude`. And MongoDB queries will not work without the correct order.

Comment: In fact Mongo recognizes exactly in this way - longitude then latitude. And GeoJsonPoint is from org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo - so it's pretty much related to integration of Mongo and Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close with this line:

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions
    .builder()
    .codecRegistry(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry())
    .build();
```

But to use GeoJsonPoint class you need to implement [Codec](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/codecs/#codec) interface and then register it in the following way:

```
CodecRegistry registry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
    CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new GeoJsonPointCodec()), // the codec you need to implement
    MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()
);
```

You can use this registry in the options builder.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I'll try to follow it and be back with results.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no luck with it. I still find the same error after implementation of Codec and registering it as you suggested. 
I suppose there is somewhere a place where `decoder` object gets overridden with default set of codecs.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data do you use? I will look at this.

Comment: it's spring-data-mongodb 1.10.6
spring-data-commons 1.13.6

Comment: Could you show de codec example for this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

cbartosiak, thank you so much for answer! It helped me a lot. But the workaround was super-super unobvious!:)

In fact the registry was required but I couldn't manage to register UNTIL i changed the aggregation interface to

```
AggregationResults<AggregatedPolygon> result = template.aggregate((TypedAggregation<?>) aggregation, AggregatedPolygon.class);
```

So I just needed to add cast to `TypedAggregation` the `aggregation` object and remove Collection name from interface.

That's really weird but it worked for me this way.